# How to get datagrid cell object form its template field wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, datagrid, datatemplate

Below is the sample code which I am using. I have created attached property for `TextBox` called `ErrorMessageServce.ErrorMessage`. Whenever the `ValidationError` was populated it will call the property-change event of `ErrorMessageService`.

From there what I want is, I want to highlight that particular cell if there was an error. so i thought to do in `ErrorMessageServicePropertyChanged`, but there I am getting `TextBox` object.

So question is:

1) How to get Datagridcell from that textbox object;

or:

2) How to higlight that particular cell;

3) How to display that particular cell in edit mode(i.e.. Textbox should be displayed)

**XAML:**

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                Width="150" Height="25">
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource ValidatingTextBox}"  
                x:Name="NameText" Text="{Binding CompanyName,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" App:ErrorMessageService.ErrorMessage="{Binding ValidationResult,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="150" Height="25">
            </TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

`ErrorMessageService`

```
public static class ErrorMessageService
{       
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValidationErrorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ErrorMessage", typeof(ValidationResult), typeof(ErrorMessageService),
       new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(ValidationResult), ErrorMessageServicePropertyChanged));

    public static ValidationResult GetErrorMessage(Control control)
    {
        return (ValidationResult)control.GetValue(ValidationErrorProperty);
    }

    public static void SetErrorMessage(Control control, object value)
    {
        control.SetValue(ValidationErrorProperty, value);
    }      

    private static void ErrorMessageServicePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       //here i am getting d as textbox , from this how to get datagridcell object , so that i can highlight
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have tried the below and it worked fine to get the Datagridcell object from textbox inside cell edit template. I guess it may help someothers too

```
  public static T FindAncestor<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
        where T : class
     {
        DependencyObject target = dependencyObject;
        do
        {
            target = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(target);
        }
        while (target != null && !(target is T));
        return target as T;
       }
```

after getting the DatagridCellobject , it's having property like IsEdit, making that true makes that cell editable

Thanks